# Retain type information while jackson serialisation and unserialize accordingly

Tags: java, jackson

I am stuck in a use case where I have an Object of Class A lets say a, and an Object of class B lets say b, b intern has a member variable of a subclass of Class C lets say c.
My use case is that I want to serialize/deserialize a in such a way that while serializing I add a type variable to member c with which I can recognize while subclass the object belongs to. I am trying to achieve this via Jackson. Refer to the code below:

```java
Class A{
B b;
}

Class B{
C c;
}

Class C {
}

Class D extends C{
int a;
}

Class E extends C{
string b;
}
```

Expected when I have C c = new D(), B b = new B(c), A = new A(b):

```
"A":{
    "B":{
        "type":D
        "C":c
    }
}
```

Comment: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html

Comment: What does the title of your question have to do with its body? Choose the right title.

Comment: done sorry for that thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try avro (or some third-party libraries)?

https://docs.oracle.com/database/nosql-12.1.3.0/GettingStartedGuide/avroschemas.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I went ahead and used jackson mixIn functionality for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses I was able to do this using, @jb-nizet's answer using JsonTypeInfo with JsonSubTypes.
Here are the annotations I used:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = D.class, name = "D"),
               @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = E.class, name = "E")})
```

Because I could not edit class C because of ownership reason I use this with a mixIn class. Here's how I created it:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = D.class, name = "D"),
               @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = E.class, name = "E")})
abstract class CMixIn {

}
```

Here is how I used the mixIn class:

```java
private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().addMixIn(C.class, CMixIn.class);
```

Now To serialize Object a of class A:

```java
String serializedString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(a);
```

To deserialize the above string:

```java
objectMapper.readValue(serializedString, A.class);
```